# Why does the program gets stuck at a certain value of the for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop

The for loop in the class Process, does not go beyond a certain value, i.e. it gets stuck at 2. I went through the code in debug mode but no use, everything went fine until 't' was equal to 1 but when 't' took the value of 2, I was thrown out of the debug mode and on the top it said thread main(running). I have posted my code and a snapshot below.

```js
//The class Agent

public class Agent {

 public Agent (){
  
 }
 
 
 public int x_cor = 0;
 public int y_cor = 0;
 
 public int time = 100;
 
 
}

// The class Complimentary

public class Complimentary extends Agent {
 
  public String comp_id;
  
  public Complimentary (){
   
  }
  
 public double skill_comp = 0; // Skill set 
 public double skill_low_min = 1 ;
 public double skill_low_max = 3 ;
 public double skill_med_min = 4 ;
 public double skill_med_max = 6 ;
 public double skill_high_min = 7 ;
 public double skill_high_max = 9;
 
     
 public int vision_comp; // Vision of the agents
 public double knowledge_comp; // Knowledge, which is a sum of both skill and vision
 public double action_first_comp ; 
 
 public int assign_x_cor (int i){
  x_cor = i ;
  return x_cor;
 }
 
 public int assign_y_cor (int j){
  y_cor = j ;
  return y_cor;
 }
  
  public String calculate_comp_id (int i){
   String newStr= "comp";
   comp_id = newStr +String.valueOf(i);
   return comp_id ;
  }
  
  
 public double calculate_skill_base_comp (int n){
   if(n==0){
    skill_comp = skill_low_min + (double)(Math.random()*((skill_low_max - skill_low_min)+1));
    }
    if(n==1){
    skill_comp = skill_med_min + (double)(Math.random()*((skill_med_max - skill_med_min)+1));
    }
    if(n==2){
    skill_comp = skill_high_min + (double)(Math.random()*((skill_high_max - skill_high_min)+1));
    }
    return skill_comp;
  }
  
  public int calculate_vision_base_comp(int n){
      if(n==0){
     vision_comp = 1;
    }
   if(n==1){
     vision_comp = 2;
   }
    if(n==2){
     vision_comp = 3;
   }
     return vision_comp;
   }
  
 
  
  public double calculate_knowledge_base_comp(){
   knowledge_comp = skill_comp + vision_comp;
  return knowledge_comp;
   }
 
 
}// Close class Complimentary 


// Class Comp_Behaviour

public class Comp_Behaviour extends Complimentary {

 public Comp_Behaviour (){ 

 }

 public double action_first_comp ;
 public int first_action_index_comp;

 public int total_actions = 100; // The total number of actions every user and comp agent has access
 // to
 public int [] mean_comp = new int [total_actions]; // the mean of every action

 public double std_dev_comp = 0; // The std. deviation of every action


 public  double weight_comp;

 public  int[][] action_taken_comp = new int [time][total_actions] ; // Index for the actions taken
 public  double [][] reward_comp = new double [time][total_actions]; // Storing the rewards for every action
 public  int[] action_change_comp = new int [time]; // If the action was changed or not
 public double [][] mem_payoff_time_action_comp = new double [time][total_actions]; // Stores the pay-off at every time for the action taken


 public void initialize_all_comp_behaviour(int total_actions ){
  //int t = minutes;
  int actions = total_actions;

  for (int ij = 0; ij < time ; ij++){
   action_change_comp[ij] = 0;
   for (int ac= 0; ac < actions ; ac++){
    action_taken_comp[ij][ac] = 0;
    reward_comp[ij][ac] = 0;
    mem_payoff_time_action_comp[ij][ac] = 0;
    sign_payoff_comp[ij][ac] = 0;
   }
  }
 }

 public int[] calculate_mean_comp(){
  for (int p = 0; p < total_actions ; p++ ){
   mean_comp [p]= (p + 1);
  }
  return mean_comp;
 }


 public double calculate_std_dev_comp (){ 
  std_dev_comp =  (1/skill_comp);
  return std_dev_comp;
 }
 
 // positive zone and negative zone
    public double [] zone_positive_comp = new double [total_actions];
    public double [] zone_negative_comp = new double [total_actions];
 public void calculate_zone_comp(){
  for(int p = 0; p < total_actions; p++){
   zone_positive_comp[p] = mean_comp[p] + std_dev_comp ;
  }
  for(int p = 0; p < total_actions; p++){
   zone_negative_comp[p] = mean_comp[p] - std_dev_comp ;
  }
 }

 public double calculate_first_action_comp(){ 
  double first_action_dis;
  double first_action_trial;
  Random rno = new Random ();
  first_action_dis = rno.nextGaussian() + knowledge_comp;// know is the mean and first action is chosen.
  first_action_trial = Math.floor(first_action_dis*10); // first action
  if (first_action_trial > total_actions ){
   do{
    Random rxo = new Random ();
    first_action_dis = rxo.nextGaussian() + knowledge_comp;// know is the mean and first action is chosen.
    first_action_trial = Math.floor(first_action_dis*10);
    } while (first_action_trial > total_actions);
   action_first_comp = first_action_trial;
   }
  else{
   action_first_comp = first_action_trial;
  }
  return action_first_comp;
 }

 public int calculate_first_action_index_check(){
  int p = 0;
  for ( p=0;p < total_actions ;p++){ // Remember that p has to be less than the total number of actions
   if(action_first_comp == mean_comp[p]){
    first_action_index_comp = Math.abs((p)); 
   }
  }
  return first_action_index_comp;
 }

 // Weight

 public double attach_this_weight_comp(int minutes){ // minutes is the "t" of time
  int t = minutes;
  int p;
  for (p = 0 ; p < total_actions ;p++){
   if (action_taken_comp[t][p] == 1){
    if (vision_comp == 1){
     if (sign_payoff_comp[t][p] == 1  ){
      weight_comp = 0.1 ;
     }
     else{
      weight_comp = - (0.1); 
     }
    } 
    if (vision_comp == 2){
     if (sign_payoff_comp[t][p] == 1 ){
      weight_comp = 0.2 ;
     }
     else{
      weight_comp  = - (0.2); 
     }
    }
    if (vision_comp == 3){
     if (sign_payoff_comp[t][p] == 1 ){
      weight_comp = 0.3 ;
     }
     else{
      weight_comp  = - (0.3); 
     }
    }
   }
  }
  return weight_comp;

 }

 // Pay_off matrix

 public double[][] pay_off_comp(int minutes){
  int t = minutes;
  int p = 0;
  if (t ==0){
   for(p=0; p < total_actions;p++){
    if (p == first_action_index_comp){
     Random rm = new Random();
     double first_payoff = rm.nextGaussian()*std_dev_comp + mean_comp[p];
     mem_payoff_time_action_comp[0][p] =  first_payoff;
    }
   }
  }
  else{
   for (p=0; p < total_actions;p++){
    if (action_taken_comp[t][p]==1){
     Random rm = new Random ();
     mem_payoff_time_action_comp[t][p] = rm.nextGaussian()*std_dev_comp + mean_comp[p]; 
    }
   }
  }
  return mem_payoff_time_action_comp; // make the default in this with zeros
 }
 
 // if pay-off is good or bad
  public int[][] sign_payoff_comp = new int[time][total_actions];
  public int[][] decide_payoff_good_bad_comp(int minutes){
   int t = minutes;
   for(int p = 0 ; p < total_actions ; p++){
    if(action_taken_comp[t][p] == 1){
   if(mem_payoff_time_action_comp[t][p] < zone_positive_comp[p] && mem_payoff_time_action_comp[t][p] > zone_negative_comp[p]){
    sign_payoff_comp[t][p] = 1 ; // good payoff
   }
   else{
    sign_payoff_comp[t][p] = 0 ; // bad payoff
   }
   }
   }
   return sign_payoff_comp;
  }
  
  
  public int sign_comp;
  public int decide_good_bad_now_comp(int minutes){
   int t = minutes;
   for(int p = 0 ; p < total_actions ; p++){
    if(action_taken_comp[t][p] == 1){
     if(sign_payoff_comp[t][p] == 1){
      sign_comp = 1;
     }
     else{
      sign_comp = 0;
     }
    }
   }
   return sign_comp;
  }
 
 // Methos to return timely
 public double pay_off_comp;
 public double calculate_timely_payoff_comp (int minutes){
  int t = minutes;
  for(int p = 0 ; p < total_actions ; p++){
   if (action_taken_comp[t][p] == 1){
    pay_off_comp = mem_payoff_time_action_comp[t][p];
   }
  }
  return pay_off_comp;
 }

 // Action taken
 public int[][] action_taken_index_comp(int time){
  int t = time ;
  int p =0;
  int q = 0;
  double value_compare = 0;
  int action_p = 0;
  if(t==0){
   for(p = 0; p <total_actions;p++ ){
    if (p == first_action_index_comp){
     action_taken_comp[0][p] = 1;
    }
   }
  }
  else{
   if(action_change_comp[t] == 1){
    value_compare = reward_comp[t-1][0];
    for(q=0;q< total_actions ;q++){
     if (reward_comp[t-1][q] > value_compare){ //As the action is yet to be taken at 't' , the reward that will be used belongs to the time 't-1'
      value_compare = reward_comp[t-1][q];
      action_p = q;
     }
    }
    for(p = 0; p < total_actions ; p++){
     if (action_p == p){
      action_taken_comp[t][p] = 1;
     }
    }
   }
   else{
    for(q=0; q< total_actions; q++){
     if(action_taken_comp[t-1][p] ==1){
      action_taken_comp[t][p] = 1 ;
     }
    }
   }
  }
  return  action_taken_comp; // returns the index of the action taken 
 }

 
 
 // Action taken every time
public int take_action_comp;
  public int calculate_action_index_timely_comp(int minutes){
   int t = minutes;
   for(int p = 0; p < total_actions ; p++){
    if (action_taken_comp[t][p] == 1){
     take_action_comp = p;
    }
   }
   return take_action_comp;
  }
 
  
  // Reward

 public double[][] calculate_reward_comp(int minutes){
  int d = 1; 
  int t = minutes;
  int p = 0;
  int q = 0;
  if (t ==0){
   for (  p= 0 ; p < total_actions ; p++){
    if (p == first_action_index_comp){
     if (sign_payoff_comp[t][p] == 0 ){
      reward_comp[0][p] = d + (weight_comp* mem_payoff_time_action_comp[0][p]); // no need to take absolute value here
     }
     else{
      reward_comp[0][p] = d + (weight_comp* mem_payoff_time_action_comp[0][p]);
     }
    }
    else{
     reward_comp[0][p] = d;
    }
   }
  }
  else{
   for( q = 0 ; q < total_actions ; q++){
    if(action_taken_comp[t][q]== 1){
     if(sign_payoff_comp[t][q] == 0 ){
      reward_comp[t][q] = (reward_comp[t-1][q]) + (weight_comp* mem_payoff_time_action_comp[t][q]) ; // no need to take absolute value here
     }
     else{
      reward_comp[t][q] = (reward_comp[t-1][q]) + (weight_comp* mem_payoff_time_action_comp[t][q]) ; // no need to take absolute value here 
     }
    }
    else{
     reward_comp[t][q] = reward_comp[t-1][q]; 
    }

   }
  }
  return reward_comp;
 }

 // Calculate the reward cummulative
public double reward_usual_comp;
  public double calculate_timely_reward_comp (int minutes){
   int t = minutes;
   for (int p = 0; p < total_actions ; p++){
    if (action_taken_comp[t][p] == 1){
     reward_usual_comp = reward_comp[t][p];
    }
   }
   return reward_usual_comp;
  }


 // Action Change 

 public int change_the_action(int minutes){
  int t = minutes;
  int q;
  int p;
  int pos = 0;
  int neg = 0;
  int cnt = 0;
  int r = 0;
  for (r = 0; r < total_actions ; r++){
   if (action_taken_comp[t - 1][r] == 1){
    if( sign_payoff_comp[t-1][r] == 1  ){ // replace mem_payoff_time_action_comp[t-1][r] > 0  with sign_payoff_comp[t-1][r] == 1 
     action_change_comp[t] = 0; // no change in action
    }
    else{
     for (q = (t-1);action_change_comp[q] ==1;t--){
      cnt = q; 
     }
     for (p =(t-1);t== cnt;t--){
      if(sign_payoff_comp[p][r] == 1 ){ // replace mem_payoff_time_action_comp[p][r] > 0 with sign_payoff_comp[p][r] == 1 
       pos = pos + 1;
      }
      else{
       neg = neg + 1;
      }
     }
     if (neg == (pos/2)){
      action_change_comp [t] = 1;
     }
     else{
      action_change_comp[t] = 0;
     }
    }
   }
  }

  return action_change_comp[t];
 }


} // Close Comp_Behaviour
```

These are the three classes I have, I have used inheritance. I am new to JAVA and this is my first attempt with inheritance.
Please find below the class where I call the instances of the above class.

```js
public class Seek {

 public Seek (){

 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
  int total = 6;
  int time = 100;

  int X_matrix = 2;
  int Y_matrix = 2;
  int Agent_matrix = ((X_matrix) * (Y_matrix));

  int total_user = (Agent_matrix/2);
  int total_comp = (Agent_matrix/2);

  if (total_user == total_comp){
   total = total_user;
  }
  else{
   System.out.println("ERROR");
  }

  // Creating Complimentary instances
  int actions_comp_run = 100;
  Comp_Behaviour [] many = new Comp_Behaviour [total] ;

  for(int i = 0; i < total ; i++){
   many[i] = new Comp_Behaviour ();
  }

  // Initializing the Complimentary instances

  int n = 0;
  int c = 0;
  int l = 0;
  int x = 0;
  int y = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < total ; i++){
   n = c-l;
   if(n==0){
    many[i].comp_id = many[i].calculate_comp_id (i);
    many[i].x_cor = many[i].assign_x_cor(x);
    many[i].y_cor = many[i].assign_y_cor(y);
    many[i].skill_comp = many[i].calculate_skill_base_comp(n);
    many[i].vision_comp = many[i].calculate_vision_base_comp(n);
    many[i].knowledge_comp = many[i].calculate_knowledge_base_comp();
    many[i].mean_comp = many[i].calculate_mean_comp();
    many[i].std_dev_comp = many[i].calculate_std_dev_comp ();
    many[i].initialize_all_comp_behaviour(actions_comp_run );
   }
   if(n==1){
    many[i].comp_id = many[i].calculate_comp_id (i);
    many[i].x_cor = many[i].assign_x_cor(x);
    many[i].y_cor = many[i].assign_y_cor(y);
    many[i].skill_comp = many[i].calculate_skill_base_comp(n);
    many[i].vision_comp = many[i].calculate_vision_base_comp(n);
    many[i].knowledge_comp = many[i].calculate_knowledge_base_comp();
    many[i].mean_comp = many[i].calculate_mean_comp();
    many[i].std_dev_comp = many[i].calculate_std_dev_comp ();
    many[i].initialize_all_comp_behaviour(actions_comp_run );
   }
   if(n==2){
    many[i].comp_id = many[i].calculate_comp_id (i);
    many[i].x_cor = many[i].assign_x_cor(x);
    many[i].y_cor = many[i].assign_y_cor(y);
    many[i].skill_comp = many[i].calculate_skill_base_comp(n);
    many[i].vision_comp = many[i].calculate_vision_base_comp(n);
    many[i].knowledge_comp = many[i].calculate_knowledge_base_comp();
    many[i].mean_comp = many[i].calculate_mean_comp();
    many[i].std_dev_comp = many[i].calculate_std_dev_comp ();
    many[i].initialize_all_comp_behaviour(actions_comp_run );
   }
   c = c +1;
   if (n ==2){
    c = 0;
   }

   y = y + 1;
   if (y == Y_matrix){
    y = 0;
    x = x + 1;
   }
  }
  
  for (int t = 0; t < time ; t++){
   for (int i = 0; i < total ; i++){
    if((many[i].comp_id).equals("comp" +String.valueOf(i))){// Comp 
     System.out.println("Comp name" + many[i].comp_id );
     System.out.println("time" + t );
     if (t < 1){
      System.out.println("enter this loop only when time is 0" + t );
      many[i].action_first_comp = many[i].calculate_first_action_comp();
      System.out.println("comp first action:" + many[i].action_first_comp);
      many[i].first_action_index_comp = many[i].calculate_first_action_index_check();
      System.out.println("comp first index:" + many[i].first_action_index_comp);
     }
     if (t != 0){
      System.out.println("Always enter this loop when t > 0 zero" + t);
      many[i].action_change_comp[t] = many[i].change_the_action(t);
      System.out.println("exit of this loop");
     }
     System.out.println("comp action change" + many[i].action_change_comp[t]);
     many[i].action_taken_comp = many[i].action_taken_index_comp(t);
     many[i].take_action_comp = many[i].calculate_action_index_timely_comp(t);
     many[i].mem_payoff_time_action_comp = many[i].pay_off_comp(t);
     many[i].pay_off_comp = many[i].calculate_timely_payoff_comp(t);
     many[i].sign_payoff_comp = many[i].decide_payoff_good_bad_comp(t);
     many[i].sign_comp = many[i].decide_good_bad_now_comp(t);
     many[i].weight_comp = many[i].attach_this_weight_comp(t);
     many[i].reward_comp = many[i].calculate_reward_comp(t);
     many[i].reward_usual_comp = many[i].calculate_timely_reward_comp(t);
     System.out.println("action taken" + many[i].take_action_comp);
     System.out.println("payoff" + many[i].pay_off_comp);
     System.out.println("weight" + many[i].weight_comp);
     System.out.println("reward" + many[i].reward_usual_comp);
     System.out.println("sign of current payoff" + many[i].sign_comp );
    }
    
   }
  }
  
  } catch (Throwable ex){
   System.err.println("Uncaught exception - " + ex.getMessage());
         ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
  }

 }// Close Main

} // Close Seek
```

Now, in Class Process, the value of 't' in the for loop does not exceed beyond 2. I tried to debug the code but I am thrown out of the debug mode once t is equal to 2.

Please find attached a snaphot of the debug mode. [image: It says Thread main(Running) but in reality it is stuck at some value of t] I have checked similar problems on stackoverflow and they recommended not using a global variable to loop through the for loop (i.e. use a local variable as an index) but I never used a global variable to index the for loop.

Apologies for sharing all the codes but I didn't wish to leave anything out.

Comment: ew, long names hurt my eyes.

Comment: You may wish to read up on Java Naming Conventions to help make your code more readable.

Comment: There's a huge amount of code here. Simplify it down to the smallest reproducible example (and you'll likely find your bug in the process).

Comment: I sure will, thanks a lot for that suggestion. However, for now if you could pls help me in situating the problem, that would be great and very helpful, thanks once again..!!!

Comment: A huge amount of code, and you didn't even post class `Process` which contains the loop that is giving you trouble... or did you actually mean class `Seek` instead of class `Process`?

Comment: No we can't  help you identifying the issue , you identify it . We are here to resolve it !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an Error in your `Comp_Behaviour` in the Method `change_the_action`.
You use a `for`-loop which looks like that

```
for (q = (t-1);action_change_comp[q] ==1;t--){
                    cnt = q; 
}
```

This loop is useless. It does nothing else than permanently set `cnt` to `(t-1)`

I think you just made a typo and want to decrease `q` instead of `t`.

Once you decrease `q` your code is running without problems.

Comment: @Etterer, thank you so much...I just dont know how I overlooked this typo. Thank a ton for going through my long list of codes, I have been going through them again and again for 2 days and couldnt not see this mistake, thanks a lot..!!!